# Thread existing as long as an object in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a following topic.

In python, I want to have a class such that when an object is created, the constructor spawns a thread the thread runs a function which belongs to that object and the function keeps looping as long as the object exists.Finally, when object is to stop existing the destructor tells the thread to stop looping.

The problem is That this is a circular dependency which results in an endless loop

Here is an example of the idea that I have (it's just the mechanic described above, without anything specific to my application)

```
import threading
import time

class TestLifeThread:
    def __init__(self):
        print("^ constructor")
        self.life_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.lifetime)
        self.life_thread.start()
        self.shutdown = False
        print("! started thread")
        print ("$ constructor")

    def __del__(self):
        print("^ destructor")
        self.shutdown = True
        print ("$ destructor")

    def lifetime(self):
        print ("^ thread")
        while not self.shutdown:
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("! thread")
        print ("$ thread")


print ("^")
t = TestLifeThread()
print ("!")
time.sleep(2.5)
print ("$")
```

And here is an output:

```
^
^ constructor
^ thread! started thread
$ constructor

!
! thread
! thread
$
! thread
! thread
! thread
! thread
! thread
! thread
! thread
! thread
! thread
! thread

Process finished with exit code -1
```

(It was interrupted by me)

What's happening here:
When reaching end of main function object should be destroyed (and if I'm not using the thread, that's exactly what happens) and the destructor should make the thread stop
(in this case by the shutdown variable) however the thread is keeping a reference to the object too, as long as it is running and it has to have a reference to self - I want it to perform useful actions on the object, parallel to external actions. And this is preventing the destructor from ever being called. Thus closing the cycle.

I think, from the description it should be clear what I tried to achieve and why this simple approach can not work (also "del" will not help here either)

All I want is the object to have a parallel thread as long as it exists.

I am aware that I can simply add methods to the class which start or stop the thread. Or even call them init and cleanup methods.

But I want to avoid having to do this if possible I want the user of my library to simply use the objects like regular variables with some fields and methods without having to worry about creating / destroying /initialising / cleaning up the object. I wanted the constructor / destructor to take care of all this.
But as seen above, I could not make it work.

At this point I don't have an idea how to achieve my goal. And this is why I am looking for advice.

B.

Comment: This is probably a job for a context manager.

Answer (score 1):

`__del__` can be problematic. In your code, you depend on `__del__` being called to shutdown the thread. But python will attempt a join of the thread before a global variable finally goes out of scope and is deleted. You could make it a daemon thread to skip the join and your code will work. (also, initialize variables used by the thread before starting the thread).

```
import threading
import time

class TestLifeThread:
    def __init__(self):
        print("^ constructor")
        self.shutdown = False
        self.life_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.lifetime)
        self.life_thread.daemon = True # FIX - make daemon
        self.life_thread.start()
        print("! started thread")
        print ("$ constructor")

    def __del__(self):
        print("^ destructor")
        self.shutdown = True
        print ("$ destructor")

    def lifetime(self):
        print ("^ thread")
        while not self.shutdown:
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("! thread")
        print ("$ thread")


print ("^")
t = TestLifeThread()
print ("!")
time.sleep(2.5)
print ("$")
```

Its best not to depend on `__del__` to clean up an object. For instance, circular references can delay del until the garbage collector runs, or may keep it from running at all. Instead, its common to have a close method. It can be used directly or via a context manager as in the following

```
import threading
import time
import contextlib

class TestLifeThread:
    def __init__(self):
        print("^ constructor")
        self.shutdown = False
        self.life_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.lifetime)
        self.life_thread.daemon = True
        self.life_thread.start()
        print("! started thread")
        print ("$ constructor")

    def close(self):
        print("^ close")
        self.shutdown = True
        self.life_thread.join()
        print ("$ close")


    def __del__(self):
        print("^ destructor")
        self.close()
        print ("$ destructor")

    def lifetime(self):
        print ("^ thread")
        while not self.shutdown:
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("! thread")
        print ("$ thread")


print ("^")
with contextlib.closing(TestLifeThread()) as t:
    print ("!")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    print ("$ context")
print("$ main")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It does indeed solve my problem.
(almost: close() is called twice but I can deal with it)
But there is still one downside which prevents this from being my total solution.
Class TestLifeThread is an example of a class which is part of a library.
User will import from module.
But main function is user code.
I will write the class, but user of library now has to remember to use contextlib.closing().
I will try to read more about contextlib and see if this can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This implements your desired approach, but is dubious.  You should do [what *@tdelaney* suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67537692/132382) instead, because you probably want your thread to stop after a certain scope is closed, rather than when a certain object happens to be deallocated.

That said, you can remove the circular dependency on `self` by making `lifetime()` a *static* method, and so not bound to `self`, and then also passing in a [`weakref`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) to self.

When the object is `__del__`eted, its weakref will return `None`.  Thus your `shutdown` flag is no longer needed:

```
def __init__(self):
    wref = weakref.ref(self)
    self.life_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.lifetime,
                                        args=(wref,))
    ....

@staticmethod
def lifetime(wref):
    print("caret")
    while wref() is not None:  # None => true object has been destroyed
        time.sleep(1)
        print("exclamatory")
    print("dollar sign")
```